# Can this problem be rephrased as optimization on a manifold?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, na.numerical-analysis, smooth-manifolds, nonlinear-optimization

I have question. I have a Riemmanian manifold $\mathcal{M}$, like an $n$-dimensional regular surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$. And I have a smooth scalar field defined on this manifold $f:\mathcal{M} \to \mathbb{R}$ (positive function).

My actual problem is discretized but I'm trying to generalize it, I don't have much experience with optimization on manifold but I do know about smooth manifolds and riemannian manifolds.

I was wondering if the problem was more suitable for a standard optimization problem (if you have like a single chart maybe you take $f \circ \phi_{\alpha} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ than this would cast in a standard optimization problem), or if problems like this (where you know in advance you have a manifold with some metric) are actually better tackled in this form. The idea would be to work out an algorithm at the last.

I have few references about optimization on manifolds and I'm slowly reading through them, it seems most of the time you have a closed form description of your manifold which actually seems to enable closed form expressions of gradients, hessians and retractions etc. In my case instead I don't really have that description (because I have a discretized mesh).

Is there any benefit you can highlight maybe? (Please let me know if I can give more details).

Comment: What are you trying to optimize?  What is the role of  the Riemann  metric?  The Fermat principle works on smooth manifold. If $x_0$ is a local minimum of $f$  then  $x_0$ is a critical point of $f$, i.e., $df(x_0)=0$.  Also at a critical point there is a well defined concept of Hessian, and if this Hessian is positive definite then that critical point is a local min.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu As an example I'm trying to optimize curvature, I have this manifold and I want to find the point whose curvature is maximum (or a local optimizer).

Comment: Here again, there are many flavors of curvature: the curvature tensor, the sectional curvatures, the Ricci curvature and the scalar curvature. Only the last is a scalar quantity and, usually,  only scalar quantities can be  optimized. Without any assumption on the manifold or the quantity you cannot expect a precise answer.

Comment: And again, given my assumption (i.e. $f : \mathcal{M} \to \mathbb{R}$) in your list you can pick the scalar curvature. I think I've given already a stricter assumption already, i.e. regular submanifolds in $\mathbb{R}^n$, or isn't this enough?

Comment: Regular submanifold is no assumption at all since by Whitney's embedding  says that  manifold can be properly embedded as a  regular submanifold. Is this manifold compact? If it is not compact, then maybe there is no absolute maximum or there could be many local maxima and no absolute maxiumum, or there could be an absolute maximum. A special case of your question is:  given a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ find its  maximum.   possible answers to this question are all possible in the more general case, and a bit more.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu I'll make my question as more specific as possible then.

Comment: That will help. The more specific, the more helpful the answer.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu I had a thought about this problem I don't think apart from compactness I cannot assume more.

Comment: In this case minima/maxima exist. Such a point is a critical point, i.e., the differential of $f$ at such a point is zero. Find all the critical  points (not easy in general) and then pick the critical point  where $f$ has the smallest value (not easy). For a Random function will have many critical points and very few will be local minima.